# Playing a MXML SoundEffect in Actionscript

Tags: flash, apache-flex, audio, actionscript, soundeffect

If I have a SoundEffect in the Declarations of a MXML component and play it in Actionscript, no sound is played:

```
<mx:SoundEffect id="mySound" source="@Embed(source='assets/sounds/my_sound.mp3')" />
```

Actionscript Code:

```
mySound.play();
```

Is that supposed to happen and if so, is there a way to play a mx:SoundEffect in Actionscript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sound Effect class is used to play the sound during effects like mouseDownEffect, mouseUpEffect etc, refer [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/SoundEffect.html) for more information. If you want to play the sound through the action script you can use [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=04_OO_Programming_09.html).

and also check your hardware specification.

Answer (score 0):

You can play the effect from AS with the sound property of the effect:

```
mySound.sound.play();
```

The method returns a `SoundChannel` object that you can use to stop the sound.